Jenkinsfile : use podman to start services
I'm quite new to the containers world so I struggle with the context we're facing:
Our developers created a web stack using podman rootless, and the images of these services are stored on an Artifactory repository. To start the web stack, they wrote the following shell script start.sh (simplified):
podman compose -f compose.yml down
podman compose -f compose.yml up -d

When I run this script on the allocated server, it works like a charm, all services are started and happy.
We wanted to automate this step with Jenkins, for example polling the Artifactory and starting the web stack again in case of a new version of a service. So I created the dedicated Jenkinsfile. A very simple one, just setting a few environment variables and running start.sh.
In the console output, everything seems okay, but then the services die only a few seconds after (I guess due to the "ephemeral" nature of a Jenkins job ?).
Is there any simple way to solve this problem ? Jenkins would be the best way to comply with our security policy.
Thanks a lot

Surely the whole point is that when the job finishes the services should stop too? Otherwise every time the job runs you'll get another copy of the services
